# CSS for stacking columns one on top of the other

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to have two columns (left column with text aligned to the **right**, right column with text aligned to the **left**) which collapse on top of each other when the document is resized below a certain width. When that happens, I also want the alignment of both texts change to **center**.

[image]

**Question: How can I achieve this using plain css (no css3 or JavaScript)?**

**Edit:** Here's my first take on the problem which stacks the columns one on top of the other when the width decreases but the alignment, of course, stays right/left.

```
<div style="max-width: 500px;">
    <div style="min-width: 240px; display: inline-block; font-weight: bold; text-align: right;">Delivery date:</div>
    <div style="min-width: 240px; display: inline-block; text-align: left;">Tuesday 24 May</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share us the code?

Answer (score 0):

Use media query for the same

HTML

```
<div style="max-width: 500px;">
    <div style="min-width: 240px; display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;" class="text-right">Delivery date:</div>
    <div style="min-width: 240px; display: inline-block;" class="text-left">Tuesday 24 May</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
text-left{
  text-align:left;
}
.text-right{
  text-align:right;
}
@media (max-width:991px){
  .text-left, .text-right{
     text-align:center;
  }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, Akash, thanks. Thing is - I can't use `@media` either. My bad I didn't mention that in the original question!

Comment: @David Thanks, I don't think that there is another way. May i know on which platform your building where you can't use any thing

Comment: This will go into emails, hence the constraints. I've tried Foundation for emails but to no avail.